# I need to figure where is this location in San fransisco

Tags: united-states

[image]
 Can I get the Lattitude Longitute of the picture in the map?

Comment: Geography trivia is off-topic in GIS SE

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/maps/@37.8020034,-122.4195713,3a,75y,69.87h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sWhHLED6mIpU6yjHdCQXrcA!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DWhHLED6mIpU6yjHdCQXrcA%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dsearch.TACTILE.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D96%26h%3D64%26yaw%3D69.873375%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. As far as I can see the picture is not geotagged - it doesn't have coordinates of the location where it was taken. Thus you cannot visualize it on a map.

Ps.: Maybe the original picture *does* have latitude and longitude in the meta data, but at least the version on imgur doesn't have them.

Comment: This is not true, you can get the location using [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) (e.g.), just drag-and-drop the picture and it will tell you where it was taken: [37.802294, -122.419710](https://www.google.com/search?q=37.802294%2C+-122.419710&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr), including some additional attributes (San Francisco, Coit Tower etc.)

Comment: It's also a very famous road in San Francisco (Lombard Street).